Should I calculate the average over all values or at each point in time to analyse?
I am trying to analyse maintenance costs of different models of cars over time. I have many models.  Some sample data for a model looks like this. For example this could all be for Ford cars and each Car ID could represent a particular model of Ford car.



Car Age (Years)
Maintenance Costs ($)
Car ID




1
62
A


2
22
A


3
235
A


4
228
A


5
403
A


1
36
B


2
130
B


3
89
B


4
30
B


5
25
B


1
59
C


2
168
C


3
118
C


4
72
C


5
471
C


1
51
D


2
126
D


3
201
D


4
92
D


5
302
D



I'm trying to understand the maintenance costs. In particular I would like to show if a particular Car ID is costing a lot more or a lot less compared to its peers, i.e. the other Car ID's.
What I want to do is work out an average cost and a standard deviation so I can plot the outliers. Say anything above or below 3 standard deviations (or possibly 2).
Question:
Should I calculate the average and standard deviations for each year, i.e. for year 1 I will average 62, 36, 59, 51, and work out the s.d. for these numbers and then determine the outliers based on this?
OR
Should I calculate the average/s.d. over the entire dataset?
I'm not too sure what the difference between the two options would be. Of course with the former the average lines and average +- 2 * s.d will be not a straight line, whereas the latter it would be a straight line.
I've seen some statistical process control charts before that have flat average lines and flat upper/lower control limits (which are average+- some multiple of s.d.) but given I have multiple Car ID rather than just looking at one Car ID I wonder if I should be calculating the average for each point for each year.
I'm interested primarily in which models of car are most expensive or cheapest compared to other models of car of the same brand.
Thank you.

In fact you could do it either way (and I will add a 3rd way of doing it), but each way will tell you a different story.
If you average over the entire dataset, you will obtain a single mean/sd for the whole dataset. One car model will be the most expensive to maintain, one will be the least. You may find some "extreme" values (I do not like the term outlier in this context) for the "5 year maintenance cost" (assuming that all your data goes to 5 years for each model?).
Now, if you average year by year, you will get 5 means/sd's. You will find that in year 1, car model A was the most expensive, but in year 2, it was model B, etc... You will now get extreme values year by year.
Or you could average year by year, but cumulatively. Average for year 1; then average for year 1+2, etc. all the way to [1+2+3+4+5]. You now have cumulative maintenance costs, and again, you can do your "extreme" value detection. Here you would need to use 5 different control charts.
Note that looking only at the grand average may not be of interest to your entire audience (they may change car before year 5). Doing it year by year is not useful either (I do not care that one model was low cost in year 3, if it was expensive in years 1 and 2; I will want to know up to year 3). And the model which was most expensive at year 5 may not be at year 3.
And then whether the identified "extreme" values would be statistically significant, or not, is a completely different question (which may or not be important for your audience), which I will not address.
